# How can I calculate the power (number of studies) needed for a meta-regression?

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression, network-meta-analysis

I would like to know how small of a beta coefficient my meta-regression is powered to detect. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You want post hoc power -  after you've done the meta-analysis? You can calculate this as a function of the standard error. 4x sample = 0.5 SE.

Comment: Yes, post-hoc power would work well. Sorry, can you explain that formula? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Post hoc power is pretty frowned upon, because it's just a transformation of the p-value. it doesn't tell you anything the p-value doesn't. If p  = 0.05, power = 0.5. A shortcut is that if p = 0.01, power is about 0.8. So you multiply the sample size, to get the standard error that gives you p of about 0.01, and that's approximately 80% power. (Otherwise you need to use non-central distributions).

Comment: (Also, if you're using random effects meta-analysis, that's not quite true, but it's probably close enough.)

Comment: Could also look into this R package: https://cran.r-project.org/package=metapower (and see the associated references).